# VB.Net and SQLite not saving

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

as the title says it's not saving

Code

```
Try
        connection()
        Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand
        'cmd.Connection = connection()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Emp SET Value = Value +1 WHERE Id='1'"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        connect.Close()
        MsgBox("Data Has been Saved !")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Failed when saving data")
    End Try
```

Basically im incrementing Log by 1 if the Id is equal to X.

the error seems to be in "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()"

[image]

Table name : Emp
Value = Integer
Id = Integer

Comment: You should display the full exception instead of just displaying a generic error. I'm sure you would get an error message that will explain the problem. What is the error in the exception?

Comment: @the_lotus and that's another problem...whenever i tried to add "ex.ToString" i get an error saying "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "System.InvalidOperationException" to type 'Integer' is not valid." pointing to "ex.ToString.

Comment: It's saying you are trying to put a string in an integer. Which line does this happen? Have you tried turning Option Strict On?

Comment: That's because [the second parameter for MsgBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/139z2azd(v=vs.90)) is an enum (integer). Concatenate your string: MsgBox("Failed when saving data. " & ex.ToString())

Comment: Ok got the real error now. screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/XMxFuLb it is pointing to "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()"

Comment: I can't see images. Just update your question with the new information you have.

Comment: You need to be the error message as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is a bug or anything... but i created another project then copy and paste everything.

weird thing is it works! but the original one still doesn't. i mean i copy and paste everything from the designer to the code and the copy worker while the original doesn't

I'm using VS 2013 Updated 5...

thank you both of you.

Answer (score 1):

Comments and explanations in-line.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Try
        'Get your connection locally
        Using cn As New SQLiteConnection("Your connection string")
            'The using blocks ensure that your database objects are 
            'closed and disposed even if there is an error.
            'You have put your Id in single quotes '1'
            'This indicates that it is a string
            'Usually an Id is a number, check your database
            Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand("UPDATE Emp SET Value = Value +1 WHERE Id='1'", cn)
                'You can pass your command text and the connection
                'directly to the command constructor
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using
        MsgBox("Data Has been Saved !")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Failed when saving data. " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

If your ID in your Where clause is not a literal and comes from user input then you need to use parameters.

Comment: Even with that i'm still getting error in "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()"

Comment: Did you check if the Id column is really a string type (Text in Sqlite)?

Comment: yes it is. the problem is gone on the copy project. but on the original it's still there.. for now i will work on the copy since it's working.